# How to make pretty URLs using route?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want pretty url. I access these records using url below. Last segment is index id to access data using it. 
http://www.example.com/order/thank_you/344

How can I convert it into 
http://www.example.com/order/thank_you

How to implement and also I want last segment in page to access the data using it.

Comment: Youshould  try this: "http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html"

Comment: Show your code what you tried to do this

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### routes.php

```
$route['order/thank_you/(:num)'] = 'thanks/thank_you/$1';
```

The left hand side is the URL accessed by the users. And the right hand side is where your request going to.

For example, the request `example.com/order/thank_you/344` is going to the function `thank_you()` of the Controller `thanks`.

`$1` is the argument. If have more than one, just `/$1/$2/`.

### The Controller

```
public function friends_profile ($id = NULL) {

    echo "This is the ID I want to thank to " .$id;

}
```

The function arguments can be passed directly by the route. `$id` is the argument passed by the URI.

By the way, check out the [Codeigniter URI Routing Guide](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html) to get more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the url not to contain the id portion you could keep it in a session var and retrieve it at the thank_you method.